# App crashes when navigating back to MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

My Apps keeps crashing when navigating back to my MvxTabsFragmentActivity.

The MvxTabsFragmentActivity consists of 4 tabs all being the same type of Fragement loading the same View but with different ViewModels. The Fragements show a simple MvxListView with a command attached that opens a new ViewModel.

When navigating back the App crashes.
logging with that:

> 03-04 16:07:09.530 I/ActivityManager(  414): Displayed MobileVision.Droid/MyApp.droid.views.SecondView: +5s373ms
>
> 03-04 16:07:10.870 I/mono-stdout( 2192): mvx:Diagnostic: 71.48 No view model association found for candidate view MyListFragment
>
> 03-04 16:07:10.942 I/mono-stdout( 2192): mvx:Diagnostic: 71.58 No view model association found for candidate view MyListFragment
>
> 03-04 16:07:11.010 I/mono-stdout( 2192): mvx:Diagnostic: 71.61 No ViewModel class specified for MyListFragment in LoadViewModel
>
> 03-04 16:07:11.386 I/Choreographer(  414): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 03-04 16:07:20.798 W/ActivityManager(  414): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
>
> 03-04 16:07:20.818 E/WindowManager(  414): Starting window AppWindowToken{5292ce60 token=Token{52c32c18 ActivityRecord{529a544c u0 MyApp.Droid/MyApp.droid.views.FirsViewModelView t9}}} timed out

Anyone any solution/idea where to search? Because no exceptions are thrown anywhere.. :-(

PS: I build exactly the same clean and simple setup like FragmentSample, but then with a simple MvXListView in the Fragment to navigate to a new screen.

**EDIT:**
 - made logging litle more readable
 - exceptions seems to happen with following scenario:

1. OpenApp
2. Navigate to other TAB
3. Navigate to new activity (by Button or ListViewItem, doesn't matter)
4. Navigate Back
5. Crash / or repeat step 3 & 4

NOTE: when NOT doing step 2 (switch TAB) it seems the App won't Crash

Comment: what does this means _No view model association found for candidate view MyListFragment_ or that_71.61 No ViewModel class specified for MyListFragment in LoadViewModel_ or other "no"-messages ? maybe this is the cause.

Comment: I have looked at it to, I load 4 of the same Fragments with 4 of the same ViewModels when the TabActivity page is loaded. Maybe its something with disposed Fragements or Viewmodels, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Kumiho What I meant with my comment is; I couldn’t figure that out and that’s why I posted this question on Stackflow. I looked at it for some ours now, and I think it has something to do with the different lifecycle with Fragments and/or MVVMCross ViewModels, but I can’t seem to get a good trace of all the moving objects within Fragments and MVVMCross.Today I will try to get a better view on the lifecycle of the Fragment, but if anyone has any tips you are very welcome to note them because I can’t imagine that I am the only one with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried the latest alphas? These contain fixes like https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/915

Comment: @Stuart, I just found it to, looked like the same issue... I works, no more crashes, TNX. Can you say something about when it will be released to NuGet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer came from @Stuart ; fixes in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/915

Currently NuGet package for FullFragging isn't working yet, need to build the FullFragging dll yourself for now.